# Button that randomises an element/variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

How can I write a simple code that can randomise a variable/element/attribute etc. when you click a button.

It will randomise, and give out an **IMAGE** chosen at random? *(I have a XML database sheet, how can I assign each element to an Image?)* **Thank you :D**

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. On top of that you haven't even shown a sample of the data or any of your html. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: sorry, my bad, how can i resolve this alternatively?

Comment: you could code a function that will store `Math.random`, then check it using a `if else` statement against numbers (ie: 1, 2, 3) and assign the image depending on the number.

Comment: It is a simple way of doing it, it is no doubt the worst way of deciding a random image. otherwise you could check the random number to an id of the xml database

Comment: Hey thanks, but if you don't mind answering, how do we exactly check the random number to an id of the database?